# How to use USB interface of R307 fingerprint module?

Tags: node.js, usb, ffi, fingerprint

I want to use the R307 fingerprint module using USB Protocol. I found an SDK for it that included a dll file. Now I want to use NodeJS to call the dll functions. So, I used node `ffi` module to call native dll functions.

DLL file link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dmcdtgajeuOvK0gH0BV2ricJ850Yo722/view?usp=sharing

DLL Documentation link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LtCfMjyISxUehI-48rJboxXjPTgBCZC8/view?usp=sharing

This is my code:

```
const ffi = require("ffi");
const ref = require('ref')

const intPtr = ref.refType('int');

const R307 = new ffi.Library("./SynoAPIEx", {
    "PSOpenDeviceEx": [
        "int32", [intPtr, "int32", "int32", "int32", "int32", "int32"]
    ],
    "PSCloseDeviceEx": [
        "int32", [intPtr]
    ],
    "PSGetImage": [
        "int32", [intPtr, "int32"]
    ]
});


const pHandle = ref.alloc(ref.types.int, 0)
const status = R307.PSOpenDeviceEx(pHandle, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0)
if (status === 0) {
    const response = R307.PSGetImage(pHandle, 1)
    console.log(response);
}
```

I first tried to connect to the R307 fingerprint sensor using the `PSOpenDeviceEx` function and received a return value of 0. According to the documentation, 0 means "OK."

Then I used `PSGetImage` function to read the fingerprint. This function accepts `pHandle` and `nAddr` as arguments. According to documentaion the value of `pHandle` will be set by `PSOpenDeviceEx` function. When I call this function I am getting `-1` as return value. And I also don't know what is the exact error. PLs help me.

Comment: Your are using `intPtr` as the type for `HANDLE`. That will work. However, `PSOpenDeviceEx` doesn't take `HANDLE` as an argument but rather `HANDLE*`. So there is an additional indirection. You need to allocate space for the `HANDLE` and then pass the allocated buffer to `PSOpenDeviceEx`. Once it succeeds, read the contents of the buffer and pass it as a value to `PSGetImage`, `PSCloseDeviceEx` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A similar type of situation is present in an example project on Github.**
An example code is available on GitHub using this `SynoAPIEX DLL`. This is the implementation of the `PSOpenDeviceEx` function in this example:
[image]

And the implementation of the `PSGetImage` function is also in next piece of code:
[image]

These lines of code are present in the `Test.cs` file under `FingerPrintDEMO` module:
[image]

Some text like comments and string messages are in Chinese language but you can easily convert them using Google Translate if you like.

Demo Application Source Code: https://github.com/Meng-Ye/SynoAPIEx-v3.035

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. I have referred to the demo you have provided and now its working.